# getting failure to count number of rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

something wrong happens to my code. I don't know why is happened and I can't get the number of rows affected.
I have 200 records in my tbl_item_events. for avoiding redundant records , I implement a simple code to avoid that. but it doesn't work. `$count=0` always `$count` is zero.

```
<?php

//class Database
class Database
{
private $username;
private $pass;
private $server;
private $database;


public function __construct(){

    $this->username='root';
    $this->pass='';
    $this->server='localhost';
    $this->database='my_db';
    $this->initial_db();

}

public function initial_db(){

    $con = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->pass) or die( 'unable to connect to database');
    $db=mysql_select_db($this->database, $con);
    if(!$db)
    die('unable to select db');
}

public function insert($row){

    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){

         $status = 2;
         $remoteAddr = 0;
         $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_events SET publish_date = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', approved_date = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', user_id = '300'";
         $query.= ",  creation_date='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', status= '".$status."', ip_address ='".$remoteAddr."'";

            foreach($row[$i] as $key => $value)
            {
                $query.=", ".$key."='".$value."' ";
            }

            if($this->avoid_redundace($row[$i]['title']))       
           $result= mysql_query($query);


    }


}

public function avoid_redundace($title){

$query='SELECT title FROM tbl_item_events WHERE title="'.$title.'"'; 
$result= mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>0)
    return FALSE;
    return TRUE;

   }

}
?>
```

Comment: please note mysql_connect is depreciated  use mysqli_connect instead

Comment: and in mysql_query you shoud pass your database connection object as a parameter check the manual

Comment: I would suggest you check the return value of `mysql_query`. if it is `result===FALSE` you have an error in your query. apart from that, use mysqli or pdo and in any case prepared queries.

Comment: @Vigikaran. `result` is not `false`. I have problem with `function avoid_redundant` which doesn't check if the `title` is existed or not. when I run the query it inserts all records again and I don't want it.

Comment: if ($result = mysql_query($query) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // there are results in $result
} else {
    // no results try this
}

Comment: @Vigikaran . as I said before , `$result=resource id='259' type='mysql result'`

Comment: @RyanVincent. it doesn't need `else` statement. because if `avoid_redu...` function return `true` then it allows to insert into table otherwise doesn't